# Are the zeros of the sum/difference of these integrals all on the critical line?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

The answers given to the question whether [all zeros in the critical strip of $\zeta(s)\pm\zeta(1-s)$ lie on the critical line](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89518/are-the-semi-trivial-zeros-of-zetas-pm-zeta1-s-all-on-the-critical-li), suggest that this can indeed be proven, however only for those zeros where $s \ne \rho$ (to be more precise; those zeros occur when $\chi(s)=2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin(\pi s/2) \phantom. \Gamma(1-s) = \pm 1$).

Now assume $s \in \mathbb{C}$, $\Re(s) \ge 0$ and take the known expression:

$$\zeta(s) = \dfrac{s}{s-1} - \frac12+s \int_1^\infty \frac{1/2-\{x\}}{x^{s+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

and substitute the fractional part of $\{x\}$ by a closed form ([derived here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468334/an-integer-counting-function-nx)):

$$\displaystyle \{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor = \frac12 + \frac{i}{2 \pi} \ln \left(-\mathrm{e}^{-2 \pi i x} \right)$$

which gives:

$$\displaystyle \zeta(s) = \dfrac{s}{s-1} - \frac12-\frac{s i}{2 \pi} \int_1^\infty  \frac{\ln \left(-\mathrm{e}^{-2\pi i x}\right)\,}{x^{s+1}}\mathrm{d}x $$

> From the discussion in the comments section below, it has become clear
>   that the various CAS-packages give different outcomes when evaluating
>   this integral. When the integral is finite from 1 to $N$, both Maple
>   and Mathematica give the correct outcome, but Sage seems to struggle.
>   The difference probably can be explained from CAS picking the correct
>   (principal?) branch of the multi-valued $\ln(-e)$ element in the
>   integral. However, despite 2 CAS results continuously improving in
>   accuracy with increasing $N$, in all CAS the integral is yielding a
>   very wrong outcome at $\infty$. This is not only the case for the
>   $\ln(-e)$ integral, but also for the integral with $\{x\}$ (which is a
>   proven formula for $\zeta(s)$). I now wonder if this has something to
>   do with how the various CAS evaluate the fractional part at infinity.
>   In any case, CAS are not going to give us the answer and some real pen
>   and paper math is required to assess what exactly happens at $\infty$.
>   Any thoughts are welcome.
>
> Since I used a finite integral in Maple to test my conjecture below
>   (**EDIT:** some zeros in the strip have been found and the conjecture has been proven wrong), I decided to be more precise in the OP and replaced $\infty$ by
>   an as large as you like $N$ in the integral below.

Isolate the integral part,

$$I(s) =\frac{s i}{2 \pi} \int_1^N  \frac{\ln \left(-\mathrm{e}^{-2\pi ix}\right)\,}{x^{s+1}}\mathrm{d}x $$

and I like to conjecture, that in the critical strip, all zeros of:

$$I(s) \pm I(1-s)$$

are on the critical line $\Re(s)=\frac12$, however now with the certainty that when $s= \rho$ then $I(s) \ne 0$.

Via the reflective relation $\zeta(s) = \chi(s)\phantom . \zeta(1-s)$, this can be simplified into the following relation:

$$I(s) \pm I(1-s) =0 \text{   when   } \displaystyle \chi(s)= \frac{\frac{s}{1-s} + \frac12 \pm -I(1-s)}{\frac{1-s}{s} + \frac12 + \hspace{3 mm} I(1-s)}$$

Appreciate any thoughts on possible approaches to proof this conjecture, e.g. based on the symmetry between the two integrals $I(s)$ and $I(1-s)$ or the symmetry around $\chi(s)$.

Thanks.

Comment: Agno, I can't compute $I(s)$. Would you please give the values of $I(3), I(1/2 + 13.35 i), I(1/2 + 20 i)$, the method to compute them and to what precision they are correct? Thank you.

Comment: Joro. I found the problem. The $\frac12$ should not be subtracted form the $x$. I tried it in Wolfram Alpha and this works. Here is the code for $\zeta(3)$ till $x=9$ :    3/(3-1)-1/2-(3*i)/(2*π)*(integral from 1..9 of ln(-e^(-2*π*i*(x)))/(x^(3+1)))

Comment: Agno, computing I(s) via zeta got some zeros off the critical line and edited the answer.

Comment: Many thanks, Joro. Always a pleasure to see the Master of Root finding in action. Looking at some of my scars from earlier discussions with you, I decided this time to explicitly limit my conjecture to the Critical Strip only ;-) Delighted to see that you did not discover (yet) any other zeros in the strip than those lying on the critical line!

Comment: Agno sorry, my mistake, didn't notice the critical strip. Edited the answer with zeros in the critical strip.

Comment: Joro, that clearly proofs the conjecture wrong and new scars have been created... Anyway, your help has been much appreciated!

Comment: Agno you are welcome. Btw, just for a change why don't you try do disprove RH via zeros of some obscure function off the line ;-)

Comment: Agno, I asked extended question for your method for the fractional part: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140084/when-does-this-method-for-integrals-of-fractional-integer-parts-work

Comment: Thanks Joro. Good idea to take the integral question separately. I am still curious to understand more about this integral and the ambivalence in evaluating it.

Comment: It is partially optimistic that maple correctly computes some {x} integrals correctly, very interesting! Is there a published reference for your {x} ?

Comment: Joro, I do not have a formally published reference, but I found the formula when I was deriving the "Integer Counting function" (link in the OP) here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SawtoothWave.html. Note that there is another function listed that uses $\tan^{-1}$ and $\cot$. Have not tried that in an integral yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Since $I(s)$ is hard to compute using the integral, searched
for zeros in the critical strip expressing $I(s)$ with zeta.

Zeros of $I(s)-I(1-s)$:

```
 (0.542373937181871507937660440099538246914 -/+ 169.9110890356259176158839120274631129439j)
```

Zeros of $I(s)+I(1-s)$:

```
 (0.7898290418725801070374041640775529742698 + 111.370199942379561610316560047101576977j)
 (0.2101709581274198929625958359224470257302 + 111.370199942379561610316560047101576977j)
 (0.2752069724061228509354681961440878521307 + 150.4900933771384115043090398407167418796j)
 (0.7247930275938771490645318038559121478693 + 150.4900933771384115043090398407167418796j)
 (0.7409784227009039316446697155153005654462 + 169.6169782129636093132302613533815909668j)
 (0.8060767456413526455641207946358500080546 + 185.1541122304347183385135208635099380142j)
```

Their location agree with the formula involving $\chi$.

---

sage/maxima found closed form for the indefinite integral (edit: in the initial 
revision of the question).

$$\int \frac{\log\left(e^{\left(-i \, {\left(2 \, x - 1\right)} \pi\right)}\right)}{x^{s + 1}} dx = -\frac{x^{-s} \log\left(-e^{\left(-2 i \, \pi x\right)}\right)}{s} + \frac{2 i \, \pi x^{-s + 1}}{{\left(s - 1\right)} s} + C$$

I doubt zeta can be expressed via limits of such simple expression.

Session:

```
sage: var('x,s');assume(s != 0);assume(s-1 != 0);ex=log(exp(-2*pi*I*(x-1/2)))/x^(1+s)
(x, s)
sage: inte=integrate(ex,x);inte
-x^(-s)*log(-e^(-2*I*pi*x))/s + 2*I*pi*x^(-s + 1)/((s - 1)*s)
sage: (diff(inte,x)-ex).full_simplify()
0
```

Comment: There is indeed seems to be a strange ambivalence in the integral occuring at infinity, however try using an ever increasing finite integral and you'll see that it perfectly approaches $\zeta(s)$. Don't know why the behavior "tilts" at infinity.

Comment: @Agno are you sure you don't have typos and the formula for zeta is correct? For s=2 the limit of the integral at x=0 is infinity... Numerically and according to maple the integral doesn't converge, might be wrong.

Comment: Pretty sure there are no typos. Try using a finite integral up to say x=100 (I used Maple). Please note that it only works for $\re(s) \ge 0$ (should have stated that!), but it certainly should work in the critical strip.

Comment: @Agno do you agree that the indefinite integral is correct?

Comment: @Agno since log(exp(x))==x, why don't you simplify the integral? Do you work with the principal branch of log() as all CAS do? (there is closed form too after the simplification).

Comment: Could you confirm whether you got the finite version of the integral indeed approaching $\zeta(s)$? To your questions: I am not entirely sure the indefinite integral is evaluated correctly (I found it in Maple as well, but given the results of the increasing finite integral, I do not trust it yet). Are you sure your proposed simplification is allowed when the power contains an imaginary component? I believe it becomes multi-valued in that case and cannot be simplified this way.

Comment: @Agno log() is multivalued and you don't specify which branch you take. The simplification is not multivalued.

Comment: @Agno Can't confirm finite version of the integral approaches zeta - it appears to diverge. Might be wrong on this.

Comment: Dang There is a typo. The integrals should start at 1 and not at 0. Sorry for this :-( Fixed it in the post.

Comment: @Joro: I disagree that $\log(\exp(t))=t$ for every purely imaginary number $t$, if $\log$ is to be understood as a function holomorphic on $\mathbb C$ with a real half-line removed. That's the whole point of writing the fractional part in that form: the cut in the domain of the logarithm provides the «integer part elimination». Your simplification only applies when you perform the analytic continuation of the logarithm, which I suspect is why the closed-form (given by the CAS using implicitely an analytic continuation, I presume) does not agree with the OP's formula.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier since log() is multivalued I agree with you. Don't get numerical support for the OP claims using the principal branch of the logarithm.

Comment: @Joro: that's another issue altogether…

Comment: Joro, Loic. Apologies for the errors. Unfortunately I am on business travel and away from my desktop. Therefore can't check my Maple code until Wednesday evening. However have fixed an error in the OP and at least it now works in Wolfram Alpha!

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier The OP fixed two critical typos and his mathematica code disagrees with his formula...

Comment: Joro. You are right. Sloppy work from my side. I should stop working this from my iPad and will fix this properly when I am back home on Wednesday. P.S. Does the Mathematica code work?

Comment: The problem is that, while the formula in the original post is correct, if you take the correct branch of the log, the integration by the CAS is not compatible with that. The integral would have to be broken up into a series of ranges $x=n $ to $x=n+1$, which just reproduces the sum for the zeta function.

Comment: @TomDickens is breaking the integral from n to n+1 enough? When I compute $\int_{1/2}^1 \{1/x\} dx$ using the OP method my result disagrees with mathematica, why so?

Comment: @joro Don't know if you have cleared this up to your satisfaction yet. Sorry I haven't gotten back to you. What I mean is that I believe Sage/Maxima has made an incorrect assumption to do the integral, since the $\log()$ changes abruptly every time the phase goes through an integer multiple of $2\pi$. I hope to write a coherent reply this weekend!

Comment: @TomDickens Thanks. Sage is confused indeed, but Maple almost always gives corrects result for integrals of frac() and floor() using the OP method. Asked and gave examples of correct integrals here:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140084/when-does-this-method-for-integrals-of-fractional-integer-parts-work