# Definite integral probably equal to zeta with known (but unusable) closed form for the indefinite integral

Tags: nt.number-theory, integration, riemann-zeta-function

Related to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140084/when-does-this-method-for-integrals-of-fractional-integer-parts-work) and 
[this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139724/are-the-zeros-of-the-sum-difference-of-these-integrals-all-on-the-critical-line) questions.

Basically got definite integral that experimentally equals 
$\zeta(s)$ both numerically and symbolically.

Closed form for the indefinite integral is known, but I can't
use the closed form for general $s$ to compute $\zeta(s)$ due to
problem with limits.

Define $$ F(x) = \{ x \} = x -\lfloor x \rfloor=-\frac{\arctan\left(\cot\left(\pi x\right)\right)}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}$$

Where the principal branch of $\arctan$ is taken. (Source mathworld).

For $\Re(s) > 0$,

$$\zeta(s) = \dfrac{s}{s-1} - \frac12+s \int_1^\infty \frac{1/2-\{x\}}{x^{s+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Using $F(x)$,
$$ Z(s) = \dfrac{s}{s-1} - \frac12+s \int_1^\infty \frac{1/2-F(x)}{x^{s+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$.

Unless multivalued functions cause problems, we should have $Z(s)=\zeta(s)$.

Symbolically $\zeta(n)=Z(n)$ at positive integers, infinite sums
for rational $s$ are found too.

E.g.
$$ Z(3) =1+3\,\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }1/6\,{\frac {2\,{\it arccot} \left( \cot \left( \pi \,x \right)  \right) +\pi \,x-\pi -2\,\pi \,{x}^{3}+2 \,\zeta  \left( 3 \right) \pi \,{x}^{3}}{\pi \,{x}^{3}}} = \zeta(3)$$

Numerically with mpmath $Z(s)$ is very close to $\zeta(s)$
(unless $t$ is large, which might be explained by numerical instability
with the integral).

For general $s, s \ne 0, s \ne 1$, Maple found closed form for
$\int \frac{1/2-F(x)}{x^{s+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

I doubt the general closed form can be used to compute $\zeta$
and Maple returns "undefined" for the limit at $1$, which confuses
me.

> Why when specializing $s$ to integers and rationals $Z(s)=\zeta(s)$
>   but the general closed form doesn't appear to work?

The closed form for the indefinite integral:
$$ {\frac {-ix\ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{i\pi \,x}} \right) }{\pi \,s{x}^{s+1}
}}+1/4\,x \left( 2-2\,s+4\,x-s{\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x
}} \right)  \left( {\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{i\pi \,x}} \right) 
 \right) ^{2}+2\,s \left( {\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}
 \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{i\pi \,x}} \right) 
+s \left( {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}
^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i}{
{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) +s \left( {\it csgn} \left( {
\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) 
 \right) ^{2}{\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}} \right) +s
 \left( {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{
{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it csgn} \left( {
\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) +
{\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi 
\,x}}-1}} \right) {\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}} \right) {
\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) -s{
\it csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i
\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x
}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) -s \left( {\it csgn} \left( {
\frac {2\,i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it 
csgn} \left( {\frac {i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) +s \left( 
{\it csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i
\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{2}+ \left( {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {
2\,i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it csgn}
 \left( {\frac {i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) -{\it csgn}
 \left( {\frac {2\,i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) {\it csgn}
 \left( {\frac {i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) +s \left( {\it 
csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) 
 \right) ^{2}+s{\it csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}
-1}} \right) {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}}
 \right) -s{\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{
{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) {\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{2\,i
\pi \,x}} \right) {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}
-1}} \right) +{\it csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{
{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i{{\rm e}
^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) -s \left( {\it 
csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}} \right)  \right) ^{3}-s \left( {
\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi 
\,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{3}-s \left( {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,
i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) 
 \right) ^{3}-s \left( {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i
\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{3}-2\, \left( {\it csgn} \left( i{
{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}} \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it csgn} \left( i{
{\rm e}^{i\pi \,x}} \right) +{\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}
} \right)  \left( {\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{i\pi \,x}} \right) 
 \right) ^{2}- \left( {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x
}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it csgn}
 \left( {\frac {i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) - \left( {\it 
csgn} \left( {\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}
-1}} \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}
 \right) - \left( {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}
}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{2}{\it csgn} \left( 
{\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right) 
- \left( {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{
{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{2}- \left( {\it csgn}
 \left( {\frac {2\,i}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{2
}+ \left( {\it csgn} \left( i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}} \right)  \right) 
^{3}+ \left( {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{
{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{3}+ \left( {\it csgn}
 \left( {\frac {2\,i{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}}{{{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1
}} \right)  \right) ^{3}+ \left( {\it csgn} \left( {\frac {2\,i}{{
{\rm e}^{2\,i\pi \,x}}-1}} \right)  \right) ^{3} \right) {s}^{-1}
 \left( s-1 \right) ^{-1} \left( {x}^{s+1} \right) ^{-1}$$

Computer friendly:

"-I/Pi/s*x/(x^(s+1))*ln(exp(I*Pi*x))+1/4*x*(2-2*s-s*csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(e\
    xp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))*csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x))*csgn(I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))-csgn(2\
    *I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))*csgn(I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))-s*csgn(2*I*exp(2*I*Pi*x\
    )/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))*csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))-s*csgn(2*I\
    /(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^2*csgn(I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))+csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(e\
    xp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))*csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x))*csgn(I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))+2*s*cs\
    gn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x))^2*csgn(I*exp(I*Pi*x))-s*csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x))*csgn(\
    I*exp(I*Pi*x))^2+s*csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^2*csgn(I/(ex\
    p(2*I*Pi*x)-1))+s*csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^2*csgn(I*exp(\
    2*I*Pi*x))+s*csgn(2*I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^2*csgn(I*exp(2*I\
    *Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))-csgn(2*I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^2+s*csgn(2*I/(exp\
    (2*I*Pi*x)-1))^2+csgn(2*I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))*csgn(I*exp(2\
    *I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))+s*csgn(2*I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))\
    ^2+csgn(2*I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^2*csgn(I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))-s*csgn(I*exp\
    (2*I*Pi*x))^3-s*csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^3-s*csgn(2*I*ex\
    p(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^3-s*csgn(2*I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^3-2*csgn\
    (I*exp(2*I*Pi*x))^2*csgn(I*exp(I*Pi*x))+csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x))*csgn(I*ex\
    p(I*Pi*x))^2-csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^2*csgn(I/(exp(2*I*\
    Pi*x)-1))-csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^2*csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x\
    ))-csgn(2*I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^2+csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x))^3+\
    csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^3+csgn(2*I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2\
    *I*Pi*x)-1))^3+csgn(2*I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))^3+s*csgn(2*I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-\
    1))*csgn(I/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))-csgn(2*I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))\
    ^2*csgn(I*exp(2*I*Pi*x)/(exp(2*I*Pi*x)-1))+4*x)/s/(-1+s)/(x^(s+1))"

Comment: Mathematica will produce LaTeX output for you.  Just wrap TeXForm[ ] around your expression.

Comment: @Stopple I made it computer friendly on purpose, maybe will add it in latex.

Comment: The latex doesn't provide much info, just added it.

Comment: formally, $\int  (\pi x^{s+1})^{-1}{\rm arctan}[{\rm cot}(\pi x)]dx = [x^{s}\pi s(s-1)]^{-1}\{[\pi x-(s-1){\rm arctan}[{\rm cot}(\pi x)]\}$, with a limit $x\rightarrow 1$ of $(3-s)[2s(s-1)]^{-1}$, without any complications.