# Are the complex zeros of $\zeta\left(\frac{s}{a}\right) \pm \zeta\left(\frac{1-s}{a}\right)$ all on the critical line for $a \lt 0, a \ge 1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

With $s \in \mathbb{C}, a \in \mathbb{R}$,

numerical evidence strongly suggests that the complex zeros in the critical strip of:

$$\zeta\left(\frac{s}{a}\right) \pm \zeta\left(\frac{1-s}{a}\right)$$

all reside on the line $\Re(s)=\frac12$ for $a \lt 0$ or $a\ge 1$. There also exist a finite few complex zeros for each $a$, but these are outside the critical strip.

When $a=1$ the formula reduces to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89518/are-the-semi-trivial-zeros-of-zetas-pm-zeta1-s-all-on-the-critical-li).

**Question:** Is there an explanation for this phenomenon (or a counter example)?

Comment: Asked related question about the X-Ray and algebraic curve:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196581/how-comes-vanishing-of-the-real-part-of-function-involving-zeta-is-very-well-app