# How good can we approximate with algebraic curve the egg shaped vanishing of $\Re \zeta(s)$ near the origin?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, riemann-zeta-function

Related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196581/how-comes-vanishing-of-the-real-part-of-function-involving-zeta-is-very-well-app)
where degree $2$ algebraic curve is good approximation to vanishing of
the real part of expression involving zeta.

Near the origin, $\Re \zeta(s)$ vanishes in egg shaped form:

[image]

> Q1 Can we fit this vanishing with algebraic curve?
>
> Q2 Can we fit this vanishing with elementary functions?

Tried without success.

Data of the form "x y" is at:  https://gist.github.com/jor0/5286418df926664836ad

---

**Added**

Got partial result about Q1.

Consider the elliptic curve $E:  y^2=A x^3 +B x^2 + C x +D$.

The choice:

```
 A,B,C,D=-0.09444040290392969, -0.5891681084104351, -0.3073264886525888,0.9864806364468722
```

gave seemingly good approximation.

$E$ plotted in dashed blue over the zeta egg:

[image: zeta elliptic egg]

> Q3 Would someone verify with high precision that the zeta
>   egg is on an elliptic curve?
>
> Q4 Are there reasons to believe or disbelieve the zeta egg
>   is on an elliptic curve?

---

The error in Juan's elliptic curve appears structured to me:

[image: error in approximation with EC]

Comment: The egg is also shown on p.3 of this paper:  http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309433

Comment: I would be surprised. All these years I have told my 
students that the zeta function could be defined as the
only one transforming this egg shape on the left half plane
$\Re(s)<0$ and taking the point $-2$ to $0$ and
$0$ to $-1/2$.  So this would give us a ``geometrical'' 
definition of $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @juan The curve might be wrong... Don't get support with high precision, though might be doing something wrong. At least Q3 might be withing reach.

Comment: Since there is a symmetry you could try doing a higher-order fit - something like $y^2=p(x)$ with a higher-degree $p()$ - with precise numerical data for a handful of points, and see what your coefficients look like...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks. If I did it right and numerical instability didn't hurt me, there is no curve of general form of degree up to $8$.

Answer (score 6):

The figure of egg is not an elliptic curve.

Since the curve pass through the point $(-2,0)$ and $(1,0)$ the equation will be
of type 
$$y^2=(ax+b)(x+2)(x-1)$$
We find the numbers $y_0$ and $y_1$ 
where $\Re\zeta(0+iy_0)=0$ and $\Re\zeta(-1+iy_1)=0$. 
To 30 digits of precision they are
$$y_0=0.993509173029369418553902132848,\qquad y_1=0.893463450180666357136821959149$$
Assuming it is a elliptic curve, it will pass through the points $(0,y_0)$ and $(-1,y_1)$
Then we solve in $a$ and $b$ the equations
$$y_0^2=-2b,\quad y_1^2=-2(b-a).$$
We get the values 
$$a=-0.094391770042380714476\dots,\quad b=-0.4935302384467507512394\dots.$$
Then, we compute
$$\zeta(1/2+i\sqrt{(a/2+b)(1/2+2)(1/2-1)})=0.00251037283054027\dots - i0.82402447042004175\dots $$
The real part is small but it is not $0$ the elliptic curve determined by the other four
points do not contain the point $(1/2,y_2)$ such that $\Re\zeta(1/2+iy_2)=0$.

To get a formal proof we should do some bounds of the errors in the above computations.
But for obvious reasons we will not do it.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. If I did it right and numerical instability didn't hurt me, there is no algebraic dependency up to degree $8$, no restriction on the curve.

Comment: The error in your approximation doesn't appear random to me. It appears structured.

Comment: Edited with plot of the error of your curve.