# Do the complex zeros of $\big(\zeta(s-1) -\zeta(s)\big) \pm \big(\zeta(1-s) - \zeta(2-s)\big)$ all (except 1 pair) reside on the line $\Re(s)=1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Or stated differently: for $s \in \mathbb{C}$ and with $\chi(s)= \pi^{-s}\,2^{1-s}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi\,s} {2}\right)\,\Gamma(s)$, do all, except a finite few, of the complex (real ones exist as well) zeros of:

$$\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}-\frac{\pm 1-\chi(s)}{\pm 1-\chi(s-1)}$$

reside on the line $\Re(s)=1$ ?

The finite few lying off the line are:

- $\pm = +$ the exceptional set: $(5.894... \pm 1.389...\,i)$ ,  $(2-
        5.894... \pm 1.389...\,i)$
- $\pm = -$ the exceptional set: $(3.006... \pm 2.438...\,i)$ ,  $(2-
        3.006... \pm 2.438...\,i)$

Could a proof for this be within reach or is it just as hard as the RH?

Thanks!

**Added** a graph of the + version on request.

[image]

Comment: You found some zeros off $Re(s) = 1$, but you also found some zeros on (or near) $Re(s) = 1$ ?  And a [possibly useful theorem](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?5,1353556,1353836#msg-1353836) (Titchmarsh p.292)

Comment: user1952009, thanks for the link and will review. I conjecture that all zeros are on the line $\Re(s)=1$ except for the finite few I listed.

Comment: Yes, but why ? Did you find many zeros on (or near) $Re(s) = 1$ ? Can you add a plot for illustrating this ?

Comment: Sure, have added the graph. I only find zeros on the line $\Re(s)=1$ wherever I probe (except for the finite small few).

Comment: and how do you know if they are on $Re(s) = 1$ or just near it ?

Comment: Great question, I can't. The only indication I have, is that for increased precisions of say 60, 120 , 300 or $n$ digits, I continue to get a $1.$ with $n$ zeros for the real part. I think to prove even one zero being **exactly** on the line requires a similar approach to what Riemann used by successfully detecting one zero rather than two in an appropriately tiny region in the complex plane. Not sure how to do that for this function though.

Comment: is it real on $Re(s) = 1$ ? (and how do you prove that $\xi(s) =s(s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s)$ is real on $Re(s) = 1/2$ ?)

Comment: When I define for $\pm=-$, $$\Xi_-(s)=s\,(s-1)\,(s-2)\,\big(\big(\zeta(s-1) -\zeta(s)\big) - \big(\zeta(1-s) - \zeta(2-s)\big)\big)$$ I do get: $$\Xi_-(s)=\Xi_-(2-s)$$ hence $$\Xi_-(1+t\,i)=\Xi_-(1-t\,i)$$ and this is real on $\Re(s)=1$. For $\pm=+$, I can do something similar by multiplying with $s\, i$ instead of $s$ giving: $$\Xi_+(s)=-\Xi_+(2-s)$$

Comment: What you wrote is unclear. **If $F(\overline{s}) = \overline{F(s)}$ and $F(-s) = F(s)$** then $F(i t)$ is real. If $F(\overline{s}) = \overline{F(s)}$ and $F(-s) = -F(s)$ then $i F(i t)$ is real.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is so difficult as the Riemann hypothesis, I will only
explain why this is so without giving complete proof.

First on the line $s=1+it$ the functions are
$$(\zeta(it)-\zeta(1+it))\pm (\zeta(-it)-\zeta(1-it)).$$
In other words $2\Re(\zeta(it)-\zeta(1-it))$ and $2i\Im(\zeta(it)+\zeta(1-it))$.

We have by the functional equation
$$\zeta(it)-\zeta(1-it)=(\chi(it)-1)\zeta(1-it).$$
For $t$ real and $t\to+\infty$ we have
$$\chi(it)-1=\Bigl(\frac{t}{2\pi}\Bigr)^{1/2}e^{i(-t\log\frac{t}{2\pi}+t+\frac{\pi}{4})}(1+O(t^{-1/2})).$$
The argument of $\zeta(1-it)$ is $O(\log t)$ [$O(\log\log\log t)$ under RH] and is zero at  points  $t_k\to+\infty$
(If taken $-\pi/2$ at $z=1$).

Therefore function $2\Re(\zeta(it)-\zeta(1-it))$ has approximately 
$\frac{T}{\pi}\log\frac{T}{2\pi}-\frac{T}{\pi}$ zeros in the interval $0<t<T$.

That these are essentially all zeros of this functions need a little work, 
but I think it is possible to prove it by counting the number of all zeros
and comparing.

The other function is treated analogously.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. the function we are considering is real (resp. purely imaginary) on $Re(s) = 1$, and since its sign oscillates at $t \to \infty$, it has infinitely many zeros on $Re(s) = 1$. You suggest its number of zeros up to height $T$ is approximatively $\frac{T}{\pi} \log\frac{T}{2\pi}-\frac{T}{\pi}$, but you have no argument for saying it doesn't have infinitely many zeros off $Re(s) = 1$

Comment: For proving $F(s)$ has a finite number of zeros off $Re(s) = 1$ you'll need a function $\Phi(s)$ such that $\text{arg} (\frac{F(s)}{\Phi(s)})$  is bounded on $Re(s) = a<1$ and $Re(s)= b > 1$

Comment: @user1952009  But it is easy to obtain asymptotic expansion for vertical lines far of the critical strip. I said I will not give the details.

Comment: I meant $\text{arg}(\frac{F(s)}{\Phi(s)})$ on $Re(s) = 1 \pm \epsilon$. With your method, I think you will be able to show that all but finitely many zeros are in the strip say $Re(s) \in [-2,4]$

Comment: @user1952009  I have localized  (T/pi) log(T/2pi)-T/pi  in the line sigma=1.

Comment: @user1952009  I have localized  (T/pi) log(T/2pi)-T/pi  in the line sigma=1. That these are all need a work.  That the missing zeros are at most O( log T) is easy.  I think it can be proved that there is at most a finite number off sigma=1.

Comment: You have shown $F(s)$ has $\frac{T}{\pi}\log\frac{T}{2\pi}-\frac{T}{\pi}+ \mathcal{O}(\log T)$ zeros ($\mathcal{O}(\log \log T)$ under the RH) on $Re(s) = 1$, and on $Re(s) \le -2$ or $Re(s) \ge 4$ :  $\text{arg}(F(s)) = \text{arg}(\chi(s)+\chi(2-s))+  \mathcal{O}(1) = \frac{T}{\pi}\log\frac{T}{2\pi}-\frac{T}{\pi}+  \mathcal{O}(1)$, so there is $ \frac{T}{\pi}\log\frac{T}{2\pi}-\frac{T}{\pi}+  \mathcal{O}(1)$ zeros in $Re(s) \in (-2,4)$ and at most $\mathcal{O}(\log T)$ zeros in $Re(s) \in (-2,4), Re(s) \ne 1$. But why you think  it is possible to obtain a better bound, I have no idea.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Juan. Your proof would be very interesting especially since the spacing between the zeros seems quite irregular (contrary to for instance the proof of this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89324/are-all-zeros-of-gammas-pm-gamma1-s-on-a-line-with-real-part-frac12). Wondered whether for your proof you did apply similar techniques as used in this http://web.yonsei.ac.kr/haseo/p21-reprint.pdf or this https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.1266v1.pdf paper?